# on the classification of singular points

Tags: terminology, reference-request, calculus, differential-geometry

After reading this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89103/who-first-cared-about-singular-points) and the answers to it, I am interested o know who were the first mathematicians who started classifying singular points of curves: i.e. different kind of nodes, of cusps etc., and when it reached the stage of the classification we use today? For example, a classification already appears in "The elements of the differential calculus" from 1839 of [Young](https://archive.org/details/elementsofdiffer00youn), but it seems to draw its conclusions from an existing investigation. If so, where did it appear earlier?

Thank you, 
David

Answer (score 1):

It's Julius Plücker who is at the origin of studies involving invariants relating the number of different singular points of a curve. He used duality as a mean of finding and proving his results, especialy the recently found "reciprocal polars transformation". See the (not fully satisfying) article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_formula?oldid=360847971 (its french counterpart is slightly richer). It was around 1831 that he made his first publication on the subject. See also the interesting document https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01158895/document

Comment: Thank you! But I have seen in the meantime that the book "Introduction à l'analyse des lignes courbes algébriques" of Cramer (1750) already classified (or started the classification) singulr points. I am aware of Plücker formula, but this already belongs to more "advanced" stage, I would say. Wasn't also a classification by Euler or Newton?